# What is the difference between Skip and Don't Copy buttons in Copy File dialog?

Tags: windows-7

This is a silly question.

In Windows 7/Vista when a user trying to copy multiple file, it looks like he has five options:

1. Copy and Replace
2. Don't Copy
3. Copy, but keep both files
4. Skip
5. Cancel the operation.

It looks to me that option 2 (Don't Copy) is the same as 4 (Skip).  However, it's kind of strange for Microsoft to put two buttons that perform the same action.  I probably miss something.

Could you please tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's for DAUs which are familiar with the old replace window and are immune against learning new things..

Comment: I'd like to learn something new.  What does DAU stand for?

Comment: well.. it's for german "Dümmster anzunehmender User" which is like "most dumb user ever imaginable"

Answer (score 0):

Correct, they are virtually the same in function.

However, it doesn't seem strange to me at all that Microsoft would do something absolutely redundant and stupid.

Consider: If you open up "Computer" and click on "Organize" then select "Folder and Search Options", click the "View" tab.  You see a whole bunch of checkboxes...  Except for... Hidden Files and folders!  Now tell me, what is the functionality difference between two radio buttons (on/off) or one checkbox (on/off)? I think it's been that way since Win95?  Inane inconsistencies in UI design.

Answer (score 0):

Its the same as the difference between Abort and Fail.